# Microsoft CRM Dynamics GP Using database after CRM License Expires

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

my company wants to stop using GP but would like to retain all the historical data (for reporting) from the Great Plains 2010 system .  Can someone please advise if I can just take a backup of the Great Plains database after the license expires and run reports in SSRS from the old database? Please advise what the best approach should be.

Answer (score 1):

If your reports currently run correctly in SSRS you are good to go - there is no SSRS dependency on Dynamics GP (just the SQL database.)

You can easily test this scenario. Create a new SQL Server Instance. Take a backup of your existing GP company database(s) and restore them to the new SQL Server instance (configure security the same as your production instance.) Now, create copies of your reports and give them a new data source pointing to the new SQL Server instance. Verify that all of the copied reports run successfully.

This is the equivelent to not using GP any longer as there will be no application pointing at the restored databases - just plain old SSRS reports reading from a SQL database.

Comment: i will  continue my research based on you suggestion.

Comment: For clarity, there is no mandatory server side component for core Dynamics GP capability (this is well documented - all that is required is the Dynamics GP desktop client pointed to a company database on SQL Server. Therefore, it is impossible for the SQL Server Reporting Services to have a dependency on the Dynamics GP for accurate reporting.